# Finding vectors for a given span

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have a span $V =  
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     3a-b \\
>     4b \\ a
>   \end{bmatrix} $, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Determine a number of vectors for which $V$ is the span.

I know how to go from vectors to span, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone give some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
    3a-b \\
    4b \\ a
  \end{bmatrix}=a \begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    0 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    4 \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}$